# select inside loop oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written a stored procedure with a query inside a loop.
This query sets the records into a custom data type of the type RECORD  something like

```
TYPE finalrecord
IS
  RECORD
  (
    corh           VARCHAR2(1),
    myspissueid    NUMBER(10),
    mypkey         VARCHAR2(10),
    mycreated      DATE,
    myprevstepname VARCHAR2(10),
    mystepname     VARCHAR2(10),
    mystorypoints  NUMBER(2) );

  myfinalrecord finalrecord;
```

The for loop goes like

```
for vh in (select * from table1 where abc=3)
loop

select steps.current_or_history,
    steps.issueid,
    steps.pkey,
    steps.created,
    steps.prev_step_name,
    steps.step_name,
    steps.story_points

from steps where column1 = 'xyz' and column2=vh.column2;


end loop;
```

Every time the inner loop is executed, the SELECT statement would return more than one record. I want to add this record to a main variable (as a collection..but varray or nested table or associative array) and return that variable as a output of the stored procedure.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare
  type t is table of finalrecord;
  my_table t;
begin
  for vh in (select * from table1 where abc = 3) loop

    execute immediate 'select finalrecord(steps.current_or_history,
        steps.issueid,
        steps.pkey,
        steps.created,
        steps.prev_step_name,
        steps.step_name,
        steps.story_points)

    from steps where column1 = ''xyz'' and column2=vh.column2' bulk
                      collect
      into my_table;

  end loop;
end;
```

you can try this if it works you can also create procedure...

Comment: How do i return this "my_table"? i mean the return type of this procedure should be this "my_table"